# How to get specific campaigns by name from Facebook Marketing API using Python?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to get a list of specific ad campaigns by name from my Facebook business ad account using the Facebook Marketing API package in Python. I want to select only campaigns that match a certain name but I keep getting just a list of the 25 most recently created campaigns. How would I do this in Python?

I haven't been able to find any examples for the right syntax for the "params" argument in the "get_campaigns" command. I would think that if I wanted to select just the campaigns named "Campaign-X" and "Campaign-Y" it might look something like this, if I could match 2 values to 1 key in a dictionary:

```
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebookads.adobjects.campaign import Campaign

app_id = 'xxxxx'
app_secret = 'xxxxx'
access_token = 'xxxxx'
FacebookAdsApi.init(app_id, app_secret, access_token)
account = AdAccount('act_xxxxxxxxx')

account.get_campaigns(fields=[Campaign.Field.name], params={'name': ['Campaign-X', 'Campaign-Y']})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use the `filtering` parameter to do this, which can do things like filtering results based on string matching:

`filtering=[{'field':'campaign.name','operator':'CONTAIN','value':'Campaign-x'}]`

However, I'm not sure it's possible to do OR operations with this so you'd need a pattern that matches all of the campaigns you need.

The alternative is to do the filtering in code.

Comment: I was able to get that to work in the Graph API Explorer on the Facebook dev site, but I'm having trouble translating that into Python. when i do `account.get_campaigns(fields=[Campaign.Field.name], filtering=[{'field':'campaign.name','operator':'CONTAIN','value':'Campaign X'}])` it says `TypeError: get_campaigns() got an unexpected keyword argument 'filtering'`

This is what I have in the API Explorer, which works fine:
`act_XXXXXXXXX/campaigns?fields=name&filtering=[{'field': 'name', 'operator': 'EQUAL', 'value': 'Campaign X'}]`

Comment: You need to include this in the `params` so something along the lines of:
`account.get_campaigns(fields=[Campaign.Field.name], params=['filtering':[{'field':'campaign.name','operator':'CONTAIN','va‌​lue':'Campaign X'}]])`

Comment: The correct `params` syntax is `params={'filtering':[{'field':'campaign.name','operator':'CONTAIN','va‌​lue':'Campaign X'}]}`. The out-most component is a dictionary enclosed by `{}`.

Comment: Just a note on  RyanLeiTaiwan's solution: If you barebones copy paste it you might get an "invalid keys" error from the API: Just remove the "value" text and rewrite it in UTF-8 and it will work. (Maybe it was my IDE that messed up copy pasting, not sure, but in the end this worked).